# Istanbul js Incorrect code coverage report because of required file

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, code-coverage, istanbul

Istanbul generates an artificially low coverage report because of required files that are tested in earlier code.

Example:

test.js

```
require('./test/aTests.js');
require('./test/bTests.js');
require('./test/cTests.js');
```

aTests.js or bTests.js

```
var a = require('../a.js);
// Test resulting in very high coverage of a.js
```

cTests.js

```
var c = require('../c.js);
// Tests covering every line of c.js
```

c.js

```
var a = require('./a.js');
var b = require('./b.js');

mobule.exports = class c {
    constructor() {
         // c module depends on a and b
         this.a = new a();
         this.b = new b();
    }
}
```

What I'm seeing is that I have nearly 100% code coverage on the rest of my codebase but when I add `c.js` to `test.js` the number rockets downwards. According to my lcov every line in the file is tested (its quite short) but because it depends on the majority of the codebase those required files report as untested the second time they are `require()`d.

Here are some screenshots.

With every file in the codebase.
[image: Testing with all files shows 66% of lines]

Without the final file "`c.js`"
[image: Testing with all but the primary file shows 100% of lines]

From looking at the number of lines tested in both cases it is clear that this is in error. I can also confirm this by stripping `a` and `b` from `c` as dependencies and checking coverage at 100%.

Has anyone found a solution to this? How can I accurately generate coverage for a module that depends on other modules in the library?

Comment: I don't think you should require your test files at test.js, but instead place them all in some directory and run them. Any test runner has an option like that, if it doesn't than you're using an old or a bad test runner.

Comment: It's necessary for part of my build process, and you may be right that that's not a standard build flow but it doesn't change the outcome of this issue for me. I'm using mocha as my runner.

Comment: In that case we have to wait for santa :P